# my python socket program gives to me OSError

Tags: python, sockets, flask

List item

when I write a thread in my socket program, it gives me  Transport endpoint is not connected and its strange for me

this is my code:

-server-side:

```
from ast import arg
from audioop import add
import socket
import threading

soc_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc_port = 5053
soc_server.bind(('127.0.0.1',soc_port))
def sendfunc(soc_client , list = []):
    if soc_server.recv(1024):
        text = soc_server.recv(1024)
        list += text.decode('utf-8')
        print(text.decode('utf-8'))
        soc_client.sendall(text.encode('utf-8'))
    else:
        soc_client.sendall(f'hello from server')


soc_server.listen(5)
for i in range(5):
    soc_client , addr = soc_server.accept()
    print('connected to : ' + addr[0])
    # thread1 = threading.Thread(target=recvfunnc, daemon=False , args = (soc_client))
    # thread1.start()
    # text = soc_server.recv(1024)
    thread  = threading.Thread(target=sendfunc, daemon=False,args=(soc_client , list))
    thread.start()
```

client-side:

```
import socket
soc_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

soc_port  = 5053
soc_client.connect(('127.0.0.1',soc_port))

a = soc_client.recv(1024)
print(a.decode('utf-8'))
soc_client.sendall(b'hellp')
soc_client.close()
```

Comment: Please include full stacktrace and error message in your question so that it is easier to find out where exactly the error happens

Comment: Please add in which line of client or server error occurs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if soc_server.recv(1024):
>     text = soc_server.recv(1024)
> ```

You cannot read from the server socket. This should have been `soc_client` and not `soc_server`. Apart from that the code likely does not what you intended - it will first read *up to* 1024 bytes from the socket and discard the result. Then it will read another *up to* 1024 bytes into `text`.